# Appium Python element.send_keys('+123456789') failed

Tags: python, appium

Appium Python `element.send_keys('+123456789')` failed.

Tried 
`self.driver.press_keycode('81') #81 is the keycode of android device.`

Also tried 
`element.send_keys('+123456789')` and failed.

How to send these keys (#, +, * etc...) to an edit text field in appium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try element.send_keys("+123456789"). Make sure you have the correct locator. Please do mention error message in the details.

Comment: The "+" is not in the first page of the android default keypad, so when sending "+" by send_key() will pop up error.

Comment: you can replace + with 00 to call, unless + is must